# Athena get percentiles boundaries

Tags: sql, performance, statistics, amazon-athena, presto

Having the following schema of model's predictions over time per user:

| timestamp | user_id | model_id | version | prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-22 05:29:36.344 | 1 | model_a | 1 | [0.1226] |
| 2022-06-22 05:29:41.307 | 1 | model_a | 1 | [0.932] |
| ... | 1 | model_a | 1 | ... |
| 2022-06-22 05:29:43.511 | 2 | model_a | 1 | [0.0226] |
| 2022-06-22 05:29:43.870 | 2 | model_a | 1 | [0.132] |
| ... | 2 | model_a | 1 | ... |

I would like to select the last prediction per user (by timestamp), then take the result vector and calculate the boundary values of 100 percentiles. I have come out with the following query that get the job done:

```
with preds as
(select user_id, last_prediction
from
    (select user_id, round(prediction[1],5) last_prediction, timestamp curr_ts, max(timestamp) over (partition by user_id) max_ts
    FROM "my-schema"."my-table"
    where date(timestamp) BETWEEN date('2022-08-08') AND date('2022-08-09')
    AND version = '1' AND model_id = 'model_a')
where curr_ts = max_ts),

with_ntiles as
    (select *,NTILE(100) OVER(ORDER BY last_prediction) calculated_ntile
    from preds)

select calculated_ntile, min(last_prediction) min_pred, max(last_prediction) max_pred
from with_ntiles
group by 1 order by 1
```

Result:

| # | calculated_ntile | min_pred | max_pred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.00172 | 0.00261 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.00263 | 0.00305 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.00305 | 0.00345 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm looking for a more elegant and maybe a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to change from windows function to ordinary group by with `max_by` aggregate for the first CTE:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (timestamp, user_id, model_id, version, prediction) AS (
    VALUES (timestamp '2022-06-22 05:29:36.344', 1, 'model_a', '1', array[0.1226]),
        (timestamp '2022-06-22 05:29:41.307', 1, 'model_a', '1', array[0.932]),
        (timestamp '2022-06-22 05:29:43.511', 2, 'model_a', '1', array[0.0226]),
        (timestamp '2022-06-22 05:29:43.870', 2, 'model_a', '1', array[0.132])
)

-- sample query
select user_id, 
    max_by(round(prediction[1],5), timestamp) last_prediction
FROM dataset
where date(timestamp) BETWEEN date('2022-06-21') AND date('2022-08-09')
    AND version = '1' AND model_id = 'model_a'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Output:

| user_id | last_prediction |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.9320 |
| 2 | 0.1320 |